# Template class CArray compile under gcc, Error: the class which used as a parameter of a function undeclared

Tags: c++, templates, gcc

```
#ifndef _ALLOCATOR_H
#define _ALLOCATOR_H


#include "ace/OS_NS_stdio.h"
#include "ace/OS_NS_string.h"


#include "ace/MMAP_Memory_Pool.h"
#include "ace/Malloc_T.h"
#include "ace/Null_Mutex.h"
#include "ace/PI_Malloc.h"

#include "ace/OS_NS_unistd.h"
#include "ace/Thread_Mutex.h"
#include "ace/Process_Mutex.h"

#include <string>
using namespace std;

class CAllocator
{
public:
    CAllocator();
    ~CAllocator(void);

public:
        bool Create(char* strPoolName);
        void Destroy();

public:
        char* NewMem(char* strBlockName,int nBlockSize);
        char* FindMem(char* strBlockName);
        bool  FreeMem(char* strBlockName);

private:
        typedef ACE_Malloc_T <ACE_MMAP_MEMORY_POOL,
                ACE_Process_Mutex,
                ACE_PI_Control_Block>
                ALLOCATOR;

        ALLOCATOR* m_pAllocator;
};


#endif //_ALLOCATOR_H


#ifndef _ARRAY_H
#define _ARRAY_H

#include "allocator.h"

template<typename T>
class CArray
{
public:
    bool CreateArray(CAllocator* pAllocator,char* strArrayName,int nArraySize);    
    bool OpenArray(CAllocator* pAllocator,char* strArrayName);
public:
    CArray()
    {
        m_pArrayData = NULL;     
    }                                         

    ~CArray()
    {
        m_pArrayData = NULL;
    }

public:
    T*     GetObject(int nIndex);
    int    GetArraySize();

private:
    T*        m_pArrayData;
};

#include "array.cpp"
#endif //_ARRAY_H
```

In the function **CreateArray** of the template class CArray,
the **gcc compiler** says **CAllocator has not been declared**.
but all the code **worked under vs2010**

***please help,thanks gurus***
[image]

Comment: Please stop naming like `_ALLOCATOR_H`. Name start with `__` or `_` followed by a capital letter is reserved for using by compiler and standard.

Comment: Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: change
#ifndef _ALLOCATOR_H
#define _ALLOCATOR_H

to
#ifndef ALLOCATOR_H
#define ALLOCATOR_H

Everything is ok!
Thank u all

Answer (score 0):

Please stop naming like `_ALLOCATOR_H`. Name start with `__` or `_` followed by a capital letter is reserved for using by compiler and standard.
                    – Danh

change #ifndef _ALLOCATOR_H #define _ALLOCATOR_H to #ifndef ALLOCATOR_H #define ALLOCATOR_H Everything is ok! Thank u all – Jack